# How do I do a privacy blur on a section, selection, or region of an image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, mask, blur

On [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54483317/4561887) I see this image, with portions of it blurred out for privacy/security reasons:

[image]

How do I do this in GIMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

*Tested in GIMP 2.8.22 in Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (installed with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gimp`).*

Select a region to blur --> click **Filters** --> **Blur** --> **Gaussian Blur...** --> in the box that comes up, increase the "Blur Radius" to get more blur. Ensure the "Preview" box is checked. When the preview shows sufficient blur, click  the "OK" button to apply the blur.

Example:

Original image:

[image]

Here I have selected some regions to blur. I held <kbd>Shift</kbd> to add multiple selections with the "Rectangle Select Tool":

[image]

Select the "Gaussian Blur..." tool:

[image]

Turn on the "Preview", increase the "Blur Radius" to get the desired effect, and click "OK" when done:

[image]

When done, export the new image with **File** --> **Export As...** --> name the file with a `.jpg` extension for JPEG. The default compression "Quality" setting of `90` is fine.

Here is the end result for a blur radius of 15:

[image]

### References

1. Where I learned the gist of the info. above: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-blur-images-and-background-using-gimp
2. I used the "Edit" feature of the Shutter tool in Linux Ubuntu to do the yellow highlighting above. See here to enable the "Edit" tool: https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/

Comment: Gimp 2.8 is completely obsolete. In 2.10 the UI is different (the blur preview is done directly on the image).

Comment: @xenoid, I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @xenoid, thank you. Meanwhile, we've got a well-documented, viable solution via my answer that probably just needs a few tweaks to be updated.